# Unable to click element while testing on IE

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Below code is working fine in chrome and able to switch to frame and click logout button.But in case of IE it is showing "unable to click element error".Instead of(.click()) I used (.submit()) then it is giving error like "error  executing javascript".

```
         driver.switchTo().frame("brandingTop");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]")).click();

<html>
<head><title>Software Testing Help - iframe session</title>
</head>
<body>
  <frameset id="frRoot" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" rows="125,26,*,0,0">
        <frameset id="frRoot" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" rows="125,26,*,0,0">
    <frame id="frTopLeftPane" scrolling="no" name="brandingTop" src="/BIW/Lobby/Frameset/BrandingTop.aspx?dv=1&amp;nfGuid=">
    <a style="vertical-align:top;" href="/ic/bin/logout.asp?sessionid=&amp;id=338206" target="_top">
                                <img src="/skins/BIW/NewSkin/images/logout.gif" alt=""> Logout
                            </a>
                            </frame>

    </frameset>
    </frameset>

</frameset>
</body>
```

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",AbsoluteDriverPath); 
 webdriver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
 webdriver.get(URL);
 webdriver.manage().window().maximize();
 webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         driver.switchTo().frame("brandingTop");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]")).click();
```

Comment: Can you please share Dom structure & code snippet?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: I have attached snippet of DOM structure and Code.

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone. Problem is resolved and only thing that I did is to change IE zoom level to 150% and code is working

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch frames using the frame element itself instead of name.

```
frameElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[contains(@name,'brandingTop')]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone. Problem is resolved and only thing that I did is to change IE zoom level to 150% and code is working